# How to prevent Delphi application to create GLScene log file on startup?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, glscene

My delphi application creates the following .log file on startup :

```
0    (I)    Thread ID 6168  Log subsystem started in elapsed time mode.
0    (I)    Thread ID 4620  Service thread started
312  (i)    Thread ID 4620  Temporary rendering context created
312  (I)    Thread ID 4620  Getting OpenGL entry points and extension
...
```

Where is it controlled?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check GLScene.inc for

```
// Activate Logging
{$DEFINE GLS_LOGGING}
```

To switch logging off you have to comment out that define

```
// Activate Logging
{.$DEFINE GLS_LOGGING}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is GLScene doing the logging. You can disable it by making sure that the `GLS_LOGGING` conditional is not defined in your `GLScene.inc` file.